# Setting image anchor clickable area as circle

Tags: html, css

if you have the ability to help me and you have the knowledge you need to help me then please consider this:

I have a circular logo for my website, is it possible to make the clickable area for the anchor tag into a circle to match the image?

Here's the relevant code:

HTML:

```
        <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="hheader">
            <a id="logo" href="#" title="Return to home">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sfKCJEY.png" alt="Density Art Logo">
            </a>
            <img id="motto" src="http://i.imgur.com/qN6f4fZ.png" alt="We make websites, art and more">
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
display:inline;
position: absolute;
margin: -30px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#logo:hover {
background: black;
}

#motto {
display:inline;
float: right;
margin-top: -20px;

}

.hheader {
background-color: #005073;
background-image: url(images/header.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,60,80,.8) 0%, rgba(0,80,105,.8) 50%, rgba(0,60,80,.8) 100%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background-image: url(images/header.png), -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,60,80,.8) 0%, rgba(0,80,105,.8) 50%, rgba(0,60,80,.8) 100%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background-image: url(images/header.png), -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,60,80,.8) 0%, rgba(0,80,105,.8) 50%, rgba(0,60,80,.8) 100%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background-image: urk(images/header.png), linear-gradient(rgba(0,60,80,.8) 0%, rgba(0,80,105,.8) 50%, rgba(0,60,80,.8) 100%); /* Standard syntax */
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Standard syntax */
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-top: 15px;
height: 195px;
}

.container {
width: 960px;
padding: 0 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uedwp4be/

I've made the area black on hover so you can see what I mean.

P.S Very new to CSS and HTML so please only type out beginner-friendly advice.

Thank you fully any kind and knowledgeable members who know you are going to help me greatly.

Comment: you can remove the `#logo:hover` from css

Comment: absolutely, in the jsfiddler?

Comment: yeah i know. I am suggesting you to remove the css effect on `#logo:hover`. Then it won't show black background.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uedwp4be/6/) Check  this link whether you want to achieve it or not

Comment: I included the hover to display the area of the href. When that's omitted it's clear however the whole area that's displayed as black when hoverring over the logo is a transparent area where you can click for the href. Alternatively, I want the only 'clickable' area to be the circular logo. Sorry if I'm not explaining it well, I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: Also letmedoit, I purposely made the logo overflow the header - infact I had to make a question earlier today to find out how it was done! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an image map to accomplish this.  Notice how the black only appears when you hover outside the logo, and the cursor switches to a pointer when you hover over the logo:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="hheader">
        <img id="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/sfKCJEY.png" alt="Density Art Logo" usemap="#logomap">
        <map name="logomap">
            <area shape="circle" coords="130,125,110" alt="Return to home" href="#">
        </map>
        <img id="motto" src="http://i.imgur.com/qN6f4fZ.png" alt="We make websites, art and more">
    </div>
</div>
```

The `coords` for the `<area shape="circle">` are the x-axis, y-axis, radius.  To get the "hoverable" area in the centre:

1. Measure half-way from the left (your image is ~260px wide, so "130")
2. Measure half-way from the top (your image is ~250px high, so "125")
3. Add the radius (your circle is ~220px in diametre, so "110")

Also notice that the image now has a new attribute, `usemap="#logomap"`, and that the `<map>`'s name is "logomap".

https://jsfiddle.net/uedwp4be/7/

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge and experience

Comment: Can't get this to work in firefox Quantum, no matter what coords i put in hovering over the map element in the node list in the console it is always in the center of the screen with a width of 0 and a height of 17px, which is weird. Can't get it to match my img even with usemap property added.. The area attribute is also greyed out in console..

Comment: Inspecting the elements on your Js fiddle also reveals that you map element is 0px wide & 17px which is strange as theres no-where in your code, or my code where this is specified, can anyone else add another answer explaining a little more how to use this or why the oddities...

Comment: As a side question should the psuedo css hover state be attatched to the actual image or the map, or the area?